# Docker Swarm Not Exposing Containers on Port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm just trying to use Docker Swarm to manage multiple containers (similar to a load balancer) to allow for continuous deployments. My Dockerfile isn't the issue because I can run that perfectly fine and get the app on the specified port. However, I believe the issue lies in the docker-compose.yml file

Here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nodejs:
    image: username/image
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        order: start-first
        failure_action: rollback
        delay: 10s
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000 || exit 1"]
```

Then after initiating docker swarm, I run `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml image --with-registry-auth`

Running `docker ps` shows

```
9a2188190f00   username/image:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago   Up 20 seconds (health: starting)   3000/tcp   image_nodejs.1.ctwgtm2l2z0u1jykqgmch9nwx
102d4532160b   username/image:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago   Up 20 seconds (health: starting)   3000/tcp   image_nodejs.2.jj2ztzz8myz9x72lf88br4jal
1dc5966b21f1   username/image:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago   Up 20 seconds (health: starting)   3000/tcp   image_nodejs.4.o53woh8bi1d0v91zdu06v4r5m
a89126214ee3   username/image:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago   Up 20 seconds (health: starting)   3000/tcp   image_nodejs.3.wx7kl7vow1nphmetloo059ybg
```

Running `docker service ls` shows

```
w5fm276y7b62   image_nodejs   replicated   0/4        username/app:latest   *:3000->3000/tcp
```

However, requests to localhost:3000 always show nothing running on that port. Any ideas? I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412190/docker-swarm-not-exposing-port) solution, but it only spawns one container then.

Answer (score -1):

- You need to **export** the port number
- If there are multiple services, it is recommended to set **networks**

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  nodejs:
    image: username/image
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - "3000"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    deploy:
      ....
    healthcheck:
      ....
    networks:
      - yoursnet

  nodejs2:
    ...
    networks:
      - yoursnet

networks:
  yoursnet:
    name: net_default
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Exposing ports is unnecessary. There is only one service too, just multiple replicas.